# Adding lines to a dataset according to variable

Tags: r

I have a dataset that contains a value "DoW" (Days of week) formatted like this : 1__45_7 (always 7 characters).
And I want to duplicate the lines of my dataset for each number of DoW.
For example, for this dataset:

ColA;    ColB;    DoW;
PAR;     BKK;     1_3_5__
NYC;     LON;     1_____7

If I have "1_3_5__" in the "DoW" variable, so as there are 3 numbers in this variable, I should duplicate it 2 times to have this line 3 times. 
In each duplication of the line I want one of the numbers of the initial DoW value.
So the output should be :

ColA;    ColB;    DoW;
PAR;     BKK;     1;
PAR;     BKK;     3;
PAR;     BKK;     5;
NYC;     LON;     1;
NYC;     LON;     7;

I have tried many solutions but haven't succeeded to figure it out. Do you have a clean way to do it with R?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible example. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to see how to make a minimal reproducible example. I think I might be able to help, but it is not clear to me what you want to do. An example helps both of us ;)

Comment: Hi @dario ! Thanks for your answer. I added a clear example of what i want. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  separate(DoW, into = c(paste0("Day_", 1:7)), sep = 1:6) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Day"), names_to = c(".value", "DoW"), names_sep = "_") %>%
  filter(Day != "_") %>%
  select(-Day)
```

Note that `DoW` reflects the position in the string (1 through 7), which happens in this case to be the same as the individual numbers in the string. If you wish to keep both (actual number and location in the string), then you can remove `select(-Day)` as `Day` would have the actual number.

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  ColA  ColB  DoW  
  <fct> <fct> <chr>
1 PAR   BKK   1    
2 PAR   BKK   3    
3 PAR   BKK   5    
4 NYC   LON   1    
5 NYC   LON   7
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(
  ColA = c("PAR", "NYC"),
  ColB = c("BKK", "LON"),
  DoW = c("1_3_5__", "1_____7")
)
```

Comment: It works perfectly. That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for trying to be clearer and trying to add a minimal reproducible example! This helped me to understand your question! There are probably many ways to do what you want, here is one solution using loops:

Create an example data set as in your question:

```
df <- data.frame(ColA=c("PAR", "NYC", "EEE"),
                 ColB=c("BKK", "LON", "ZRH"),
                 DoW = c("1_3_5__", "1_____7", "__"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Create an empty data.frame to recieve the results

```
resulting_df <- data.frame(ColA = character(),
                           ColB = character(),
                           Number = numeric(),
                           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Now, get the numbers from the column 'DoW' using `strsplit`

```
numbers_list <- sapply(df$DoW, strsplit, "_")
```

Finally iterate trough each row of `df` and trough each number in the corresponding entry in numbers_list (using [[1]] to get the actual content!)

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  for (number in numbers_list[i][[1]]) {
    if (!number %in% c("")) {
      new_line <- data.frame(ColA = df$ColA[i], ColB = df$ColB[i], Number = number, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
      resulting_df <- rbind(resulting_df, new_line)
    }
  }
}
```

The object `resulting_df` should now be in the correct form.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` approach to your question

```
library(data.table)

#create sample data
dt <- fread("ColA; ColB; DoW
PAR; BKK; 1_3_5__
NYC; LON; 1_____7 ", sep  =";")

#remove all underscores from DoW, split by character and melt to long format
ans <- melt( 
  copy(dt)[, paste0( "DoW", 1:length(tstrsplit(gsub("_","",dt$DoW), ""))) := 
       tstrsplit(gsub("_","",dt$DoW), "") ],
  id.vars = c("ColA", "ColB"), 
  measure.vars = patterns("^DoW[0-9]"), 
  value.name = "DoW", 
  na.rm = TRUE )
#remove unneeded variable
ans[, variable := NULL][]


#    ColA ColB DoW
# 1:  PAR  BKK   1
# 2:  NYC  LON   1
# 3:  PAR  BKK   3
# 4:  NYC  LON   7
# 5:  PAR  BKK   5
```

**explanation**

the line

```
copy(dt)[, paste0( "DoW", 1:length(tstrsplit(gsub("_","",dt$DoW), ""))) := 
     tstrsplit(gsub("_","",dt$DoW), "") ]
```

results in a temparary data.table with all splitted DoW-numbers, like this

```
#    ColA ColB     DoW DoW1 DoW2 DoW3
# 1:  PAR  BKK 1_3_5__    1    3    5
# 2:  NYC  LON 1_____7    1    7 <NA>
```

this can 'easily' be melted..